# Extremely slow connection with BCM4318 wireless card and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I'm getting terrible internet speeds on my computer running Ubuntu 14.04 with a Broadcom BCM4318 wireless card. I have 20 mb/s internet and when I run a speed test, I'm not even getting 1 mb/s. I run Speedtest from my phone while I'm at my desk and get close to 20 mb/s. I have similar results from a Windows laptop and a Windows PC, both just under 20 mb/s. I never had a problem until I upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10. I did a fresh install as well. The issue did not start right away so I'm not really sure if it could be the upgrade.

Here are a few things I've already tried:

- blacklist wl
- blacklist brcmsmac
- sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
- Set ipv6 to 'ignore'
- purging the b43 driver and manually re-installing
- purging the b43 driver and re-installing with sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

I ran the wireless script and here are the [results](http://pastie.org/9183256).

[Here is a screenshot with the results from two of the Speedtests that I ran. On the left is from the slow computer and the right is from my phone.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/282a491dqao4bmt/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-16%2020:20:53.png)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you install the driver form `Software & Updates`?

Comment: THe one showing up in Software and Updates is an STA driver which doesn't work for my card.

Comment: How strange. My one is BCM4313 and works fine here.